# use dataBinding to put images into a ListViewItem according to a web Service values

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app

I have a listview in wich each ListViewItem has a list of default images, those images will be replaced by other images if the value recovered from a web service is different from 0
this is the json data:

```
{
success: 1,
total: 2,
locals: [
{
id_local: "82",
fav: 0,
aime: 0,
aimepas: 0,
},
{
id_local: "83",
fav: 1,
aime: 1,
aimepas: 0,
}
]
}
```

I tried this code:

```
ObservableCollection<Item> Locals = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

  public async void getListePerSearch()
    {
            UriS = "URL";
            var http = new HttpClient();
            http.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            var response = await http.GetStringAsync(UriS);
            var rootObject1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NvBarberry.Models.RootObject>(response);

            listme.ItemsSource = rootObject1.locals;



                foreach (var item in listme.Items.Cast<Locals>())
                {

                    if (item.fav == 1)
                    {
                        btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow); //yellow
                        //Debug.Write("fav=1");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        btnStar.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);//Gray
                        //Debug.Write("fav=0");
                    }

                    if (item.aime == 1)
                    {
                        coeur.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/11.png", UriKind.Absolute));
                        //Debug.Write("aime=1");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        coeur.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/1.png", UriKind.Absolute));
                        //Debug.Write("aime=0");
                    }

                    if (item.aimepas == 1)
                    {
                        deslikeimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/22.png", UriKind.Absolute));
                        //Debug.Write("aimepas=1");
                   }

                    else
                   {
                        deslikeimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///images/2.png", UriKind.Absolute));
                       //Debug.Write("aimepas=0");
                   }

               }
```

and this is Locals.cs:

```
  public class Locals
{
    public int fav { get; set; }
    public int aime { get; set; }
    public int aimepas { get; set; }

}
```

and this is the xaml file:

```
<ListView  x:Name="listme">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >
   <DataTemplate >
     <Grid>
       ...
      <Button Background="Gray"  x:Name="btnStar"/>
      <Button>
           <Image Source="images/1.png" x:Name="coeur"/>
      </Button>
       <Button>
           <Image Source="images/2.png" x:Name="deslikeimage"/>
      </Button>
     </Grid>
   </DataTemplate >
 </ListView.ItemTemplate >
</ListView >
```

so my question is,how can I use DataBinding in my case
thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class Item must implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notify to the view when some of your properties changed after that you need to set your ObservableCollection Locals as ItemsSource in your List control.

Here is the doc.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx

You need to understand what is Binding How to use it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/10/12/xaml-binding-basics-101.aspx

Here is an example:

```
public class Employee : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string myUrl;
    private string myUrl2;

    public string MyUrl
    {
        get { return myUrl; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyUrl");
        }
    }

    public string MyUrl2
    {
        get { return myUrl2; }
        set
        {
            _organization = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyUrl2");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your foreach:

```
     foreach (var item in MyOriginalCollection)
            {
```

your logic here...

Locals.Add(Item);
                }

Finally you need to set your Locals Collection to your ListControl.

ObservableCollection notifies to the view when some object is added or removed.

Here is the documentation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

In Xaml

you need to personalize your ItemTemplate of your ListControl

```
<ListView x:Name="myList"
                             >


                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <Button>
                        <Image Source="{Binding MyUrl}" x:Name="coeur"/>

                        </Button>

                          <Button>
                        <Image Source="{Binding MyUrl2}" x:Name="coeur"/>

                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
```

I hope this information and example would be useful for you.

I know there are many concepts to learn.

Here a final example showing how to use Binding Approach

http://10rem.net/blog/2012/03/27/tip-binding-an-image-elements-source-property-to-a-uri-in-winrt-xaml

Comment: please mark this answer if it's useful for you! thank you!